# Select statement format Error with spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Why do I get an error when writing my select statement like this - Note the space/tab/newline next to my table name "Personnel Number"
(I know that naming convention is bad, but I had to do it, since that is the way a excel spreadsheet looks like that I have to import regularly to the table)

```
SELECT md.[Personnel Number]
FROM    MainDump md
    LEFT JOIN   EthicsManagement em
    on em.[Personnel Number] = md.[Personnel Number]
```

And I have to write it like this to not give me an error:

```
SELECT md.[Personnel Number
]
FROM    MainDump md
    LEFT JOIN   EthicsManagement em
    on em.[Personnel Number] = md.[Personnel Number
]
```

Comment: May be you have omitted a space between Personal Number and FROM clause in first query

Comment: The error message would help.

Comment: Invalid column name 'Personnel Number'.

Comment: @Santhosh Checked, and no spaces have been omited

Comment: It is generally a nightmare to use spaces in your column names. I suggest sending the Excel CSV through a server-side script that maps the column names into something less prone to these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly obvious that your column name contains a trailing line feed. If you're absolutely sure that it's not possible to rename columns, I'm not aware of any other way to type a line feed in a column literal than the one you use:

```
SELECT md.[Personnel Number
]
```

In any case, I have a strong feeling that there's a bug in your import code. I suspect that the column is the last one in the line, you've set `\n` as line separator but your file actually uses `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT md.`Personnel Number`
FROM    MainDump md
    LEFT JOIN   EthicsManagement em
    on em.`Personnel Number` = md.`Personnel Number`
```

try to use [`] key behind Esc on top left in the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I see that if you have column names with spaces in, after you set one of those columns as a Primary key, this happens.

It adds this to your column name [Column Name]]

Note the double bracket

So Main point. To avoid having random errors like this, Don't use spaces in your columns names.